# Using LINQ on SQL Server Table with Substrings, Loop Searching in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a table called `Knowledgeable` (KB) which contains `ID`, `Link` and `Title` columns.

I need to search the table to find rows which contain matches in `Title` column based on the tags the user types into the form.

I am trying to use substrings for this feature. The tags which the user types in are comma separated (unlike the kb Title) field but I am using the `String.Replace` method to replace commas with spaces.

Can I store the table in memory and then do the searching through the records? The table isn't large.

So far, I have this code:

```
int ValidSuggestions = 0;
string IndidentTagsFromFormWithoutCommas = incident.Tags.Replace(",", " ");

for (int i = 0; i < IndidentTagsFromFormWithoutCommas.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < db.Knowledgebases.Count(); j++)
    {
        //How to search the KB title field with the IndidentTagsFromFormWithoutCommas;
        //Save the results into a KBViewModel
        //ValidSuggestions++;
    }
}

if (ValidSuggestions > 2)
{
   //Take to view with the articles
}
else
{
   return RedirectToAction("AllIncidentsForThisCustomer", "Log");
}
```

The parts which are commented out im not quite sure about how to do? But this is all I have so far. How do I search/compare the title column to the `IndicentTagsFrom....` variable and can I save the results into my KB view model? which is

```
public class KnowledgebaseViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Link { get; set; }
}
```

***EDIT:***

I can't seem to draw any results. Here is my Incident controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Create(Incident incident)
    {
        KnowledgeService KS = new KnowledgeService(db);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            incident.Log.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
            incident.Log.DateTimeLogged = System.DateTime.Now;
            incident.LogID = db.Logs.Max(item => item.LogID);
            incident.EstimatedResolveDate = incident.CalculateEstimatedResolveDate();
            db.Incidents.Add(incident);
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (KS.GetSuggestionsByTags(incident.Tags.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToList()).Count() > 1)
            {
                KnowledgebaseSuggestions(incident.Tags);
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AllIncidentsForThisCustomer", "Log");
            }
        }
             return View(incident);
      }
```

And KnowledgebaseSuggestions is:

```
    public ActionResult KnowledgebaseSuggestions(String IncidentTags)
    {
        KnowledgeService KS = new KnowledgeService(db);
        ViewBag.KSResults = KS.GetSuggestionsByTags(IncidentTags.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToList());
        return View();
    }
```

Am I using your suggestions correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you rightly you can try something like this:

```
var tags = incident.Tags.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToList();
var validSuggestions = db.Knowledgebases.Where(k => tags.Contains(k.Title))
                                        .Select(k => new KnowledgebaseViewModel()
                                                    {
                                                      ID = k.ID,
                                                      Title = k.Title,
                                                      Link = k.Link
                                                    })
                                        .ToList();
//here goes if (validSuggestions > 2) ...
```

UPDATE:
If you expect that only beginings of tags should match then use:

```
db.Knowledgebases.Where(k => tags.StartsWith(t))
```

If you expect that tags from user could be just substrings of tags in db - you can use this query:

```
db.Knowledgebases.Where(k => tags.Any(t => k.Title.Contains(t)))
```

The projecting part (.Select() method) should be the same.

UPDATE 2:
If you need to reuse such query in other actions consider to use Repository pattern for queries or just wrap that logic in some KnowledgeService class:

```
public class KnowledgeService
{
   private readonly YourDbContext db;
   public KnowledgeService(YourDbContext db)
   {
       this.db = db;
   }

   public IEnumerable<KnowledgebaseViewModel> GetSuggestionsByTags(IEnumerable<string> tags)
   {
      //Here goes logic for getting suggestions
   }
}
```

Then instantiate service in controller's constructor and call `GetSuggestionsByTags` in each needed action.

UPDATE 3:
I just realized that GetSuggestionsByTags should accept string parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<KnowledgebaseViewModel> GetSuggestionsByTags(string tags)
{
     //Here Split(',') and logic for getting suggestions
}
```

Then in your actions:

```
public ActionResult KnowledgebaseSuggestions(String IncidentTags)
{
    KnowledgeService KS = new KnowledgeService(db);
    var viewModel = KS.GetSuggestionsByTags(IncidentTags);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and in other action:

```
var suggestedTags = KS.GetSuggestionsByTags(incident.Tags);
if (suggestedTags.Count() > 1)
{
    return View("KnowledgebaseSuggestions", suggestedTags);
}
```

Don't call an action inside another one because later by changing the KnowledgebaseSuggestions action you would broke Create action.

Comment: I see. What is a valid way of storing in ViewModel? Something like this ....ToList() select new  KnowledgebaseViewModel { ID = kb.KnowledgebaseID, Title = kb.KnowledgebaseTitle, Link = kb.KnowledgebaseLink };

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what are you asking me. In your question you said that table has fields ID, Title and Link. Then right on the bottom of it you specified your ViewModel class. I did a projection with .Select() extention method, I think it's valid way.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't see the edits till I reloaded oops

Comment: Also, I want to display the KnowlegdeBaseViewModel on another page different to the user input form. I have one setup but how could I pass the viewmodel to another method (which could return a view) in the the same controller?

Comment: Error. I get a red line under select saying bool contains no definition for select

Comment: From the debugger I can see I am getting a result but the KnowledgebaseSuggestions is not taking them to view

Comment: Updated my answer again.